# What is segmentation fault in C++ mysql?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using C++ to send MySQL commands to a server. Why does it say "Segmentation fault" and what does it mean? 
The output of the program when I run it is:

```
connection Succeeded
Segmentation fault
```

Edited the code to remove the i+1 line but still having same problem

the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SERVER "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASSWORD "coursework"
int main() 
{
    MYSQL *connect;
    connect=mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!connect) 
    {
        std::cout<<"MySQL Initialization failed";
        return 1;
    }
    connect=mysql_real_connect(connect, SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, NULL ,0,NULL,0);

    if (connect) 
    {
        std::cout<<"connection Succeeded\n";
    } 
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"connection failed\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    mysql_query (connect, "drop database if exists TTU;");
    mysql_query (connect,"create database TTU;");
    mysql_query (connect, "use TTU;");

    mysql_query (connect, "create table students(tnumber char(8) PRIMARY KEY,");
    mysql_query (connect, "firstname varchar(20) NOT NULL,");
    mysql_query (connect, "lastname varchar(20) NOT NULL,");
    mysql_query (connect, "dateofbirth date,");
    mysql_query (connect, "INDEX 'lastname_i' ('lastname'),");
    mysql_query (connect, "ENGINE=INNODB);");

    mysql_query (connect, "insert into students(tnumber, firstname, lastname, dateofbirth)");
    mysql_query (connect, "values (00001234, Joe, Smith, 1950-08-12);");

    MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    mysql_query (connect,"select * from students;");
    unsigned int i =0;
    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);
    unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);
    while ((row= mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL ) 
    {
        std::cout << row[i] << std::endl;
    }

    mysql_close (connect);

    std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be C++ code rather than Java.

Comment: A segmentation fault is an error that occurs when your program attempts to access memory it doesn't have permission to access. 

Without a line number at which the error is occurring (obtained using a debugger), it's difficult to determine what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: I am no expert in this particular API, but how are you sure there is an `i+1` entry here: `std::cout << row[i+1] << std::endl;`?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code. There are two major bugs: Incorrect usage of `mysql_query()`, and repeated failures to check the return value from various MySQL library functions, resulting in a failure to detect various errors.

```
    mysql_query (connect, "create table students(tnumber char(8) PRIMARY KEY,");
```

This is not valid SQL. `mysql_query()` takes a ***complete*** `SQL` statement and executes it. It doesn't take individual fragments of an SQL statement, broken down across multiple consecutive invocations, and only executes it once a complete SQL statement gets parsed.

Because the shown code fails to check the return value from `mysql_query()`, it fails to detect that this whole sequence of `mysql_query()` calls have failed, and the table did not get created.

Subsequent call also fails to check the return value from other MySQL library functions.

The shown code is likely getting a `NULL` back from `mysql_store_result()`, fails to check for it, passes a `NULL` pointer to `mysql_num_rows()`, and crashes.